# Meaning of Depth header in WebDAV PROPFIND method

Tags: webdav

I am writing something in PHP to create a virtual file system using WebDAV.

I am trying to get my head around the `PROPFIND` request method. RFC 4918 mentions something about it, but I’m not sure I understand. Can someone clarify this:

What is the role of the `Depth` value (`0`, `1`, `infinity`)? Has it something to do with folders vs files?

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

> What is the role of the Depth value (0, 1, infinity)? Has it something to do with folders vs files?

For directories:

- Depth 0: Retrieve properties of the directory
- Depth 1: as 0 + properties of all files in the directory
- Depth infinity: as 1 + properties of all files in sub-directories of the directory (recursively)

For files it has no effect.

The depth applies similarly to other WebDAV methods.

Comment: LOCK is one exception, accepting only 0 or infinity.