# Allow PROPFIND with Depth: Infinity requests in Sabre/Dav

Tags: webdav, depth, sabredav

Many [WebDAV servers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebDAV) do not allow `PROPFIND` requests while sending the `Depth: Infinity` header (see also [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31284615/meaning-of-depth-header-in-webdav-propfind-method)) which would return a description of the whole underlying file system from the specified folder and all subfolders recursively. Instead, they only allow `Depth: 0` or `Depth: 1` for security reasons which only returns the specified level of the directory tree.

Is it, despite the security issue, possible to turn this feature on in [SabreDAV](http://sabre.io/dav/)? I found [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/fruux/sabre-dav/issues/262) as well as [this changelog](http://ulso.at/sabre-dav-2.0.5/ChangeLog.md) from an older version of the software (search for `infinity`) which both suggest that this has been implemented some time ago.

However, I cannot find any hint how or where to activate it. Does anybody know this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. Call:

```
$server->enablePropfindDepthInfinity = true;
```

Comment: Cool! And where to I call this? In `server.php` before `$server->exec();`?